# Error 1045 MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a remote database which I connect through a sql management with a user and its password. The database has four tables and a view. To put the permissions I have executed the following command:

```
mysql> grant all privileges on databasename.* to 'username'@'%' identified by 'password' with grant option;
```

Then, all it's ok. When I connect to the database, I can see the data from the tables but if I explore the view, for example:

```
select * from viewname;
```

I get this error:

> Error SQL (1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'%' (using password: YES)

I don't know what is the problem, because the rest of the database is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have given the desired privileges for your user, you will need to run this command within the MySQL command prompt:

Flush the privileges with this MySQL command: FLUSH PRIVILEGES;